# dense rank price

Tags: mysql, sql

Question description: write a query to rank price and if there is a tie display the same rank

Table price

```
| Id | price |
| 1  | 3.00  |
| 2  | 3.65  |
| 3  | 4.00  |
| 4  | 3.00  |
| 5  | 4.00  |
```

Correct Result:

```
| price | Rank |    
| 4.00  | 1    |    
| 4.00  | 1    |    
| 3.65  | 2    |    
| 3.00  | 3    |    
| 3.00  | 3    |
```

**Questions:**
My query is the following, but I am not getting the correct ranking

```
SELECT  B.price, (SELECT COUNT(A.price) FROM price A 
                   WHERE A.price >= B.price) AS rank
FROM  price B
ORDER BY B.price DESC;
```

Comment: Here is a [demo](http://rextester.com/WBTLWM91697) taking the suggestion by @Felix and you can see that it is working.

Comment: it works ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Try this.....

```
SELECT  B.price, dense_rank() over (ORDER BY B.price DESC)
FROM  price B
ORDER BY B.price DESC;
```